# How can I color the background of multiple selected items in Vue?

Tags: javascript, css, vue.js

I have code below for category selection. When a category is selected, it sets its background to green, otherwise the background is gray; this works fine.

What I want to achieve is when I select multiple items, I want it to keep the background green for all selected categories. Is there a way to do this?

```html
<div class="categories" v-for="(category, index) in categories" :key="index" @click="Add( category._id, index)" :class="[isediting && selectedIndex == index ? 'green' : 'gray']">
  {{ category.category_name }}
</div>

<script>
  methods: {
      Add(AddCategory, index) {
        this.AddCategory.push(AddCategory);
        this.selectedIndex = index;
        this.isediting = true;
      },
</script>

<style>
  .green {
    background-color: #41B883;
  }
  
  .gray {
    background-color: #e5e0ed;
  }
</style>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The only major change that needs to be made to accommodate this is to make `selectedIndex` an array rather than a single value, so that we can hold more than one selection.

Eg.:

1. Set `selectedIndex` to an array `[]` in `data()`
2. When clicked, we should push the value onto the array instead of setting it equal
3. To check if a given index is selected, we use [`selectedIndex.includes(index)`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/includes) instead of `selectedIndex == index`

There's one other side effect to allowing multiple selection though, which is adding support for on-click deselection. But this is also fairly simple, we just need to check whether `selectedIndex` already contains the value in `Add()`, and if it does, remove it. We can use [`Array.prototype.splice()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/splice) to do this.

Here's an interactive version:

```js
new Vue({
  el: '#app',
  data() {
    return {
      selectedIndex: [],
      categories: [{ _id: 0, category_name: 'noodles' }, { _id: 1, category_name: 'pizza' }, { _id: 2, category_name: 'hamburgers' } ],
    }
  },
  methods: {
    Add(AddCategory, index) {
      //Check if item is selected...
      if (this.selectedIndex.includes(index)) 
        this.Remove(index); //If so, remove from selectedIndex
      else
        this.selectedIndex.push(index); //If not, add to selectedIndex
    },
    Remove(index) { //Find index in selectedIndex, and splice out
      this.selectedIndex.splice(this.selectedIndex.indexOf(index),1);
    },
    RemoveAll() { //To deselect all, we empty the selectedIndex array
      this.selectedIndex = [];
    },
  }
});
```

```css
.green {
  background-color: #41B883;
}

.gray {
  background-color: #e5e0ed;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/vue/2.5.17/vue.min.js"></script>

<div id="app">
  <div v-for="(category, index) in categories" 
    @click="Add( category._id, index)" 
    :class="[selectedIndex.includes(index) ? 'green' : 'gray']"
  >
    {{ category.category_name }}
  </div>
  <br>
  <button @click="RemoveAll">Unselect All</button>
</div>
```

Comment: i know it's too late to comment, your answer was really helpful unless the remove function didn't work properly.. it's not removing the selected index from array

Comment: The SO question "[How can I remove a specific item from an array?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/5767325)" is where I looked for help when putting together that removal function, you may find it helpful too.

Answer (score 1):

That's because you are doing it based on the `index`, so the `index` is unique and also changing on each click. Try a property for each category such as `selected` and make it false as default. Then in your click function just do `this.categories[index].selected = !this.categories[index].selected`. After that bind the class to the `category.selected` value.